# I can't insert the username in title meta tag

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am fetching the username from my sqli with this code:

```
$mem_name=$rows2['usr_name'];
```

In my html i have set the username in this code with php:

```
echo $mem_name
```

This is working fine.

I need the username to be also inserted in the meta title like this:

```
Username | Website
```

I already tried to put the code from `h1` tag

```
echo $mem_name;
```

but it doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: <?= $mem_name ?> or <?php echo $mem_name; ?>

Comment: @JimL: Thanks for showing me. Kind of a dumb error of me (tired) >.<

Comment: <?php echo $mem_name; ?>